# Are DJing questions allowed? (live mixing)

Tags: discussion

> to help with ... mixing and mastering [(from the faq)](http://audio.stackexchange.com/faq)

In general there's 2 different kinds of mixing, preparing a recorded track and mixing songs together for a live performance at a club or other venue. The first is definitely covered by this site, but I'm not sure what the intent is about the second. Since I expect the answer isn't just a simple yes or no, here's some sample questions about live mixing:

probably off topic:

- What's an easy type of music to start mixing for practice?
- What different type of scratches are there? (turntablism)
- How can I keep could rises and falls of intensity in a mix?

maybe on topic?

- What does smart-loop do in virtual DJ?
- How do software algorithms for bmp calculation usually work?
- What's the minimum quality my music files should be if I'm playing a real gig?

Feel free to post other questions about live mixing if you're not sure if they're on or off topic for discussion sake. :)

Answer (score 13):

A DJ wears two hats.  He's an engineer and an artist.
In my mind, questions related to the engineering aspect of DJ-ing are in scope, while performance-related questions are out of scope.

I'm interested to hear others' thoughts.

Comment: This is exactly what I think.  I think the same thing is true for, say, synthesizers, as well as electric guitar to an extent.

Comment: I agree with this. There's no substitute for actual questions, let's get a few DJ questions here and see how it goes.